# VBA PhotoPaint: Get layers in order?

Tags: vba

In Visual Basic for Applications, which is used by editor Corel PhotoPaint, I can grab all of a selected groups objects using

```
For Each layer In ActiveDocument.SelectedGroups.Item(1).Layers
    ....
Next layer
```

However, these layers are not in the visual stack order as in the graphics file, they are in the order as originally created. How would I get these in their correct order as shown in the CPT PhotoPaint file?

Comment: What about `ActivePage.Layers` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PhotoPaint, but does the layer object have any kind of Order property that you could sort on?

Comment: The only thing I found was "layer.IsInFrontOf(otherLayer)", which means I could probably do it manually with some workaround...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Layer object has a ZOrder property.

I'm guessing that'd give you what you're after.